# How do I link expat into a project

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake

I have project that depends on expat. My problem is that I cannot link to expat. I use Ubuntu (debian environment) and need to use cmake to build a makefile.

I´ve tried to download the source and link to it inside my CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(
...
${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/expat-2.1.0/lib
...
)
```

I have tried to move the .c-files and link to them individually:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
...
src/xmlrole.c
src/xmltok.c
src/xmltok_impl.c
src/xmltok_ns.c
src/xmlparse.c
...
)
```

Though this doesn´t work and get, when linking, error in xmlparse.c

Does somebody know how you properly link a library inside a CMakeLists.txt file? Is it necessary to download the source code and link to the file themselves (which I can´t get working)?

Is downloading the source necessary or is it possible to link to the ".so - file" that is created when running "sudo apt-get install expat"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the very latest expat version, you should be able to use `sudo apt-get install expat`.

If you want the most recent version, [download the source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/files/expat/) and extract it.  Then:

```
cd <expat root>
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr  (default install path is /usr/local)
make
sudo make install
```

Once it's installed, you can find it using CMake's [`FindEXPAT` module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module%3aFindEXPAT).

So for example,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MyTest)
include(FindEXPAT)
find_package(EXPAT REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} <list of your source files>)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXPAT_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 2):

As said you can use

> sudo apt-get install expat.

and then in the makefile with

> -lexpat

you can link to the library if exists in the $PATH.

If is installed to a different path you have to do

> -L path_of_the_library  -lexpat